# Image slider with trapezoid images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here's an image of what I'm working with: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQae1.jpg - I apologize for the quality. I can't share a better one at the moment.

Some clarification on the image: The black edges are the edges of a tablet. Inside of it is an image of a web page.

So as you can see, the shape of the white part is somewhat of a trapezoid. I am attempting to create a slider where I slide the white images (websites) into the tablet screen. The problem is, the image of the website is a rectangle and not a trapezoid. The edges are transparent so that it appears to be a trapezoid.

This is fine until we slide to the next image. Then we see that there is some transparent space between the images.

What I have tried:

- Using translateX to slide between images. With the images being back
  to back, we see the transparent space between the images. Not good.
- Using position absolute, and sliding the next image over the current one. This was no good either, since the white image's transparent part stays over the edges of the tablet, you can see the not-transparent part of the next one going over the edge.

I had one version which worked where I used clip-path: polygon but I will require IE support for this, so that's not going to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please share code which you have tried to debug easily

Comment: @NagaSaiA - Unfortunately I believe I'm not allowed to share the images, otherwise I would've posted a fiddle.

Comment: replace those images with dummy images

Answer (score 0):

oh sure, use hover

```css
.container {
  perspective: 500px;
  }
.container div {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 70vw;
  height: 50vh;
  min-height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: rotatex(-10deg);
  transition: .5s;
  }
.container div:hover {
  transform: rotatex(-40deg);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
</div>
```